# How to stop useEffect from making so many requests? Empty Dependencies don't work

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a component that updates a piece of state but I'm having issues with it

I have the state declared

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

Then in my useEffect I am

```
useEffect(() => { 
  const fetchData = async () => {
    await axios
    .get(
      API_URL,
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-API-KEY': API_KEY
        },
        params:{
          "titleId": id
        }
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      setData(response.data.Item);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("API call error:", err.message);
    }); 
  }  

  fetchData();         
  
}, [data, id])
```

If I declare "data" in my dependencies, I get an endless loop of requests which is obviously no good. But if I leave 'data' out from the dependencies it shows nothing, though I am successfully retrieving it in my network's tab and even when I `{JSON.styringify(data)}` in a div tag aI get the json content too. So the info is in the DOM, but it's not updating the components

How can I do this so I can make an initial request to load the data and not thousands of them?

I've tried the following:

- a setTimeout on the callback function
- the isCancelled way with a return (() => { callbackFunction.cancel(); })
- And there is an Abort way of doing this too but I can't figure it out. Every example I've seen is for class components

Sorry for the vague code. I can't replicate this without lots of coding and an API. Thanks in advance

Comment: await with then catch why??

Comment: @NishargShah To be frank, it's how I learned to make these calls. But I recognize I am not great at this. SHoudl I remove the async await?

Comment: Could you just remove data from the dependency in useEffect? It seems like you may want to fetch the data just when the Id changes.

Comment: @TheFlorinator That was my initial thought but as I mentioned when I do this, the components do not load with data. I'm afraid there is a racing condition and the components are loading wihtout the data existing. Even when I load the components only when data.length

Comment: Updating state within React will cause a re-render, so setData within the fetchData function should trigger a re-render. Maybe validate that it is hitting that setData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the state and then check if is different.  I use a custom hook for this which uses the useRef hook:

```
export function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);
  return ref.current;
}

const prevData = usePrevious(data);
```

I don't know what your data looks like, but build a conditional from it.  Inside of your useEffect you'll need something like:

```
if (data !== prevData) fetchData()
```

or

```
if (data.id !== prevData.id) fetchData()
```

You'll then add prevData to you dependencies:

```
 [data, prevData, id]
```

Answer (score 1):

So useEffects works with dependency.

With dependency - on changing dependency value useEffect will trigger

```
useEffect(() => {
    // code
}, [dependency])
```

With empty brackets - will trigger on initial of component

```
useEffect(() => {
    // code
}, [])
```

Without dependency and Brackets - will trigger on every state change

```
useEffect(() => {
    // code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this, if that can help. I also used `async/await` so you can check that.

```
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(API_URL, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-API-KEY': API_KEY,
          },
          params: {
            titleId: id,
          },
        });
        setData(response.data.Item);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('API call error:', err.message);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [id]);

  if (!data.length) return null;

  return <p>Yes, I have data</p>;
};
```

Comment: Update: the answer was fixed. --- I don't think this would actually solve the issue. He's likely facing an infinite loop of requests because the `data` state variable is both being set and is a dependency of the useEffect hook

Comment: that is why I removed data dependency from the useEffect

Comment: This does exactly what I explained in my question. Though the data is there ( I can see it in the networks tab and I can print it with a JSON.stringify(data). The componets are not updating with the data. My guess is a racing condition is in place. The component is renderign before the data is available

Answer (score 0):

obviously you will get an infinit loop !
you are updating the **data** inside your useEffect which means each time the **data** changes, triggers useEffect again and so on !
what you should do is change your dependencies **depending** on your case for example :

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
const [fetchAgain, setFetchAgain] = useState(false)
useEffect(()=> {
   fetchData();
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    if(fetchAgain) {
        setFetchAgain(false)
        fetchData();
    }
}, [fetchAgain])
```

now each time you want to fetch data again you need to update the fetchAgain to true

Comment: Soemthing doesnt make sense here. fetchData is out of reach in the second useEffect

Comment: fetchData should be a function in outer scope of useEffect : 
const fetchData = () => { // code here }
useEffect(()=> { // code here }, [])
useEffect(()=> { // code here}, [fetchAgain]) 
hope this is clear